# Алгоритм слияния элементов коллекций

Tags: java, алгоритм, коллекции

Здравствуйте, вот суть моей проблемы,
есть несколько коллекций:

```
private List<Order> fstBookBUY;
private List<Order> fstBookSELL;
private List<Order> sndBookBUY;
private List<Order> sndBookSELL;
private List<Order> trdBookBUY;
private List<Order> trdBookSELL;
```

`fstBookBUY`, `fstBookSELL` - это один субъект

`sndBookBUY`, `sndBookSELL` - это второй субъект

`trdBookBUY`, `trdBookSELL` - это третий субъект

Списков по 2 на каждый субъект, это потому что в одном списке, его предложения о покупке, в другом о продаже(Все отсортированы по `price`).

Каждая коллекция наполнена объектами класса:

```
class Order {
    private String book;
    private String operation;
    private int volume;
    private float price;
    private int orderId;

    Order(String book,
          String operation,
          int volume,
          float price,
          int orderId) {

        this.book = book;
        this.operation = operation;
        this.volume = volume;
        this.price = price;
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }
    // гетеры сетеры
}
```

Нужен такой алгоритм который бы проверил что у двух объектов `Order` поле `price` одинаковое, а `book` и `operation` разные, и если это так, то проводить операцию автоматически.

Ну на пример: есть два `Order` у которых

1ый ордер - `price = 10`, `operation = "SELL"`, `volume = 100`, `book = "book-1"`;

2ой ордер - `price = 10`, `operation = "BUY"`, `volume = 130`, `book = "book-2"`;

Тогда 1ый ордер вообще исчезает а у второго `volume` становится `30`

Либо если `volume` у обоих был один и тот-же они оба исчезают.

Либо если у первого ордера `volume` был больше на 20 то второй исчезает, а у первого становится 20.

Главное что `price` одинаковые и заявки с разными `book` и `operation`. Сколько смог купил/продал, что не смог, та часть запроса осталась.

Скорость имеет значение. Буду признателен и за код, и за просто мысли или идеи о том, как это можно было бы сделать. Это задание у меня завершающее по коллекциям, так что видимо надо именно основываясь на свойствах разных коллекций, придумать какую-то хитрость для ускорения работы.

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? Ты и так все описал "своим языком" осталось if'оф накодить и все. Уточните проблему.

Comment: Да ифов то я могу накодить но там 3 млн объектов а условие задачи что-бы она за 5 сек работала. Вот я и задался поиском эффективного алгоритма. А вообще задание это на знание коллекций, от меня ждут чего-то связанного с коллекциями

Comment: Так ведь если они отсортированы по `price` (а вторым полем сортировки должно идти `book` - если можно "сокращать" **только разные** `book`) - и тогда это обычное линейное слияние. сравнили два первых, либо операция, либо - оставили меньший как есть, сдвинули его список. опять сравнили - и так пока какой-то список не исчерпается, после этого второй просто копируется. O(n). Быстрее, думаю, не получится.